# Django responsive web not working properly

Tags: django

I bought a template that I'm using to develop a responsive web with django, and when I put the browser in responsive mode, the mobile version does not work properly. I attach some pictures to illustrate it:

[This is my actual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG08i.png)

[And this is the template that I bought](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9N8A.png)

As you can see, my problem is that it looks bigger than the original template. Obviously the template I bought was 100% html, so I had to use staticfiles to make it work. This is the original header of the template:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">  
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/fonts.googleapis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/icon-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/social-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/cs.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/font-icon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/spr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/slideshow-fade.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/cs.animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/themepunch.revolution.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="./assets/stylesheets/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/classie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/application-appear.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/cs.script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.currencies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/linkOptionSelectors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/social-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/javascripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

And this one is my actual header:

```
{% load static %}

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/cs.styles.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/fonts.googleapis.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/icon-font.min.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/social-buttons.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/font-icon.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/spr.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/slideshow-fade.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/themepunch.revolution.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/jquery.fancybox.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' %}" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'stylesheets/cs.animate.css' %}" media="all" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<script src="{% static 'stylesheets/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/classie.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/application-appear.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/cs.script.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.currencies.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.zoom.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/linkOptionSelectors.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/scripts.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/social-buttons.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'javascripts/jquery.fancybox.js' %}"></script>
```

The files are loaded. It's more, in the server I see no files lost, so I don't know what am I doing wrong. The web works fine in desktop version, is just the mobile one which doesn't work. If needed, I can paste other files or add more info.

Thanks

Comment: You're not linking CSS files in the same order.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked